# SSL Handshake Exception while Load test using Jmeter in Jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, ssl-certificate

Hi I am integrating the Jmeter with the opeshift pipeline using Jenkins to test my API(https). When the Jmeter is trying to send the request to the API I am getting following error:
**Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - Non HTTP response message: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching <> found**

I have tried steps to ignore the SSL certificate verification but I am unable to bypass the process.

I have created a spring boot project to run the load test as a pipeline. I am using `<groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>` and using the the jmeter file with extension .jmx to run in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

As per [SSL Encryption](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) chapter of JMeter Documentation:

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc. This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.**
>
> If the server requires a client certificate, this can be provided.

So by default JMeter will trust all certificates no matter of their validity, incomplete chain, subject not matching dns hostname, etc.

If might be the case that **your** application requires JMeter to send client certificate for security reasons, it can be done either using [SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager) or providing the relevant system properties pointing to the keystore where the certificate lives. See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more details